# How to prevent from overwriting the file?

Tags: r, file-io

I'm looking for a way to prevent R from overwriting files during the session. The more general solution then better.

Currently I got bunch of functions called e.g.: `safe.save`, `safe.png`, `safe.write.table` which are implemented more or less as

```
safe.smth <- function(..., file) {
    if (file.exists(file))
        stop("File exists!")
    else
        smth(..., file=file)
}
```

It works, but only if I got control over execution. If some (not mine) function created file I can't stop it from overwrite.

Another way is to set read only flag on files, which also top R from overwriting existing files. But this has drawbacks as well (e.g.: you don't know which files needs to be protected).
Or write one-liner:

```
protect <- function(p) if (file.exists(p)) stop("File exsits!") else p
```

and use it always when providing filename.

Is there a way to force this behaviour session wide? Some kind of global setting for connections? Maybe only for subset of functions (graphics devices, `file`-created connections, etc)? Maybe some system specific solution?

The following could be used as test case:

```
test <- function(i) {
    try(write.table(i, "test_001.csv"))
    try(writeLines(as.character(i), "test_002.txt"))
    try({png("test_003.png");plot(i);dev.off()})
    try({pdf("test_004.pdf");plot(i);dev.off()})
    try(save(i, file="test_005.RData"))
    try({f<-file("test_006.txt", "w");cat(as.character(i), file=f);close(f)})
}
test(1)
magic_incantations() # or magic_incantations(test(2)), etc.
test(2) # should fail on all writes (to test set read-only to files from first call)
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Thomas Win7. But if you got some another OS specific way I'll be happy to know.

Comment: Do you want to create a new file, or is the "append" option acceptable?   Separately -- under *nix, isn't there a command "set noclobber" or something like that?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft New file. Beside I can't imagine append to png/RData/csv without ending in mess-up. I'll check this *nix solution.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `set noclobber` prevent only overwrite by bash redirections (e.g. `>`), so no luck here.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to avoid clobbering data files isn't to look for OS hacks, but to use filenames and directories that are special for your session.

```
session.dir <- tempdir()
...
write.table(i, file.path(session.dir,"test_001.csv"))
writeLines(as.character(i), file.path(session.dir,"test_002.txt"))
...
```

or

```
session.pid <- Sys.getpid()
...
write.table(i, paste0("test_001.",session.pid,".csv"))
writeLines(as.character(i), paste0("test_002.",session.pid,".txt"))
...
```